# How to deal with this Pandas error related to dataframe.sort?

Tags: python, pandas

A dataframe 'df' :

```
>>> df = ACEV(get_SW_code('sdht', sw_cls=3))[['PB','PE','EV_EBITDA','PEG','ROIC','mg_r','opr_pft_r','net_pft_r','sales_gr','net_pft_r','Ttl_mkv']]
>>> print df
                       PB        PE  EV_EBITDA      PEG    ROIC    mg_r  opr_pft_r  net_pft_r  sales_gr  net_pft_r   Ttl_mkv
STK_ID RPT_Date                                                                                                             
000153 20130930    2.4196   96.1577    28.4962   2.4451  0.0215  0.2420     0.0169     0.0205   -0.1744     0.0205   24.4094
000513 20130930    3.6926   25.0706    18.4354   2.4541  0.1031  0.6270     0.1375     0.1171    0.1115     0.1171  119.5308
000566 20130930    3.4557   71.1281    48.0766 -10.0123  0.0624  0.3442     0.1013     0.1048    0.2624     0.1048   50.3113
000915 20130930    7.6417   36.7593    15.4284   1.0311  0.2811  0.6573     0.3108     0.1501    0.3122     0.1501   55.6988
002262 20130930   10.8237   51.6500    35.6455   2.0330  0.2355  0.3906     0.1031     0.0883    0.1175     0.0883   87.4037
002294 20130930    7.2780   26.5449    21.4806   0.7326  0.2700  0.7687     0.4328     0.3649    0.2072     0.3649  210.4453
002332 20130930    3.8046   56.5500    29.0781  -1.3127  0.0446  0.3240     0.0290     0.0323    0.2342     0.0323   43.8699
002370 20130930    5.0226 -200.3027  -737.7620   3.0019 -0.0209  0.2699    -0.0386    -0.0190   -0.0964    -0.0190   35.1696
002393 20130930    2.3108   21.3287    16.8411   3.2078  0.1590  0.6495     0.3591     0.3295    0.1034     0.3295   66.9792
002422 20130930    2.3011   18.7523    15.4236   1.7534  0.0726  0.4491     0.1920     0.1722    0.1322     0.1722  219.3120
002437 20130930    4.9315   56.5184    52.4612   1.5637  0.0700  0.7674     0.1347     0.1422    1.0571     0.1422  113.4000
002653 20130930   13.3723   46.9329    53.3025   2.3415  0.4212  0.7145     0.4425     0.4882    0.3671     0.4882  235.8229
002693 20130930    3.1935   41.3297    38.7854  -7.6784  0.0693  0.6249     0.4072     0.4565    0.0800     0.4565   27.0720
300006 20130930    5.2367  112.0564    60.3387 -16.2008  0.0406  0.3715     0.0542     0.0802    0.1406     0.0802   56.6032
300016 20130930    5.0141   41.5183    35.1102   7.8817  0.1495  0.6945     0.2276     0.2076    0.1679     0.2076   27.1893
300026 20130930    8.9274   46.4318    37.1856   1.0558  0.2022  0.8317     0.2072     0.1770    0.7922     0.1770  143.2314
300086 20130930    1.6353  109.4084    56.0711   5.9406  0.0028  0.4658     0.1238     0.0917   -0.1995     0.0917   29.0000
300110 20130930    2.9636   37.6105    22.9847   2.5999  0.0610  0.5250     0.1728     0.1443    0.5337     0.1443   40.2620
300194 20130930    2.2659   96.6729    69.7392  -1.5238  0.0137  0.3165     0.1219     0.1087   -0.2244     0.1087   38.3085
300199 20130930    8.6975   95.1120    82.4783   7.8161  0.0909  0.8133     0.4029     0.3731    0.2354     0.3731   92.6000
300254 20130930    3.3275   69.2074    38.1987   3.6941  0.0562  0.6231     0.0952     0.0618    0.2605     0.0618   20.0700
600062 20130930    2.3357   17.6355    11.1323   1.8080  0.1230  0.3112     0.1078     0.0908    0.0298     0.0908  116.5688
600079 20130930    3.2838   35.7598    17.0296  -7.0877  0.0933  0.4182     0.1281     0.0723    0.2095     0.0723  139.2799
600276 20130930    8.2268   41.4846    31.2832   2.7490  0.2097  0.7877     0.2512     0.2040    0.1232     0.2040  497.2969
600297 20130930    2.1951   66.8464    49.0453  -1.9347  0.0411  0.2627     0.0722     0.0972   -0.5125     0.0972   20.3350
600380 20130930    1.7856   30.1339    10.2166   0.7840  0.0768  0.6047     0.1231     0.0590   -0.0068     0.0590   72.6543
600420 20130930    4.5755   33.8193    19.7438   2.0176  0.0709  0.3901     0.0803     0.0471    0.2715     0.0471   43.5053
600513 20130930    4.1317   46.4486    32.1551   1.1443  0.0727  0.4439     0.0680     0.0608    0.9255     0.0608   17.0960
600568 20130930    3.0480   59.0073   217.2803  -4.5461  0.0354  0.1229     0.0455     0.0717    0.3563     0.0717   31.0560
600664 20130930    1.3296   22.9746    10.6580  -2.7641  0.0309  0.2795     0.0243     0.0192    0.0178     0.0192  109.2965
600771 20130930  123.2274   13.6873  -134.3250  -0.1349  0.0067  0.5464    -0.1835     0.0054   -0.0652     0.0054   58.3189
600789 20130930    1.9866  -32.9747    40.2872   0.7011 -0.0232  0.1285    -0.0554    -0.0307   -0.0761    -0.0307   29.1369
600829 20130930    1.7848   55.0648    21.7546  -0.4271 -0.0692  0.3676    -0.0320    -0.0289   -0.2365    -0.0289   37.4608

[33 rows x 11 columns]
>>> df = ACEV(get_SW_code('sdht', sw_cls=3))[['PB','PE','EV_EBITDA','PEG','ROIC','mg_r','opr_pft_r','net_pft_r','sales_gr','net_pft_r','Ttl_mkv']].sort('EV_EBITDA')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "D:\Python2.7\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2664, in sort
    inplace=inplace)
  File "D:\Python2.7\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2756, in sort_index
    return self.take(indexer, axis=axis, convert=False, is_copy=False)
  File "D:\Python2.7\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 1126, in take
    new_data = self._data.take(indices, axis=baxis)
  File "D:\Python2.7\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 3326, in take
    ref_items=new_axes[0], axis=axis)
  File "D:\Python2.7\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 2304, in apply
    do_integrity_check=do_integrity_check)
  File "D:\Python2.7\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 1957, in __init__
    self._set_ref_locs(do_refs=True)
  File "D:\Python2.7\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 2097, in _set_ref_locs
    'have _ref_locs set' % (block, labels))
AssertionError: Cannot create BlockManager._ref_locs because block [FloatBlock: [PB], 1 x 33, dtype: float64] with duplicate items [Index([u'PB', u'PE', u'EV_EBITDA', u'PEG', u'ROIC', u'mg_r', u'opr_pft_r', u'net_pft_r', u'sales_gr', u'net_pft_r', u'Ttl_mkv'], dtype='object')] does not have _ref_locs set
>>> 
>>> pd.__version__
'0.13.0-203-g4518630'
```

Just want to know how to fix this error caused by df.sort ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is a little confusing with all the `BlockManager`/`_ref_locs` stuff, but it seems to be because you're selecting duplicate columns (`net_pft_r`):

```
df = ACEV(get_SW_code('sdht', sw_cls=3))[['PB','PE','EV_EBITDA','PEG','ROIC',
'mg_r','opr_pft_r','net_pft_r','sales_gr','net_pft_r','Ttl_mkv']]
```

For example:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"A": range(3), "B": range(3,6)})
>>> df[["A", "B", "A"]].sort("B")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-53-12e1eca79c2b>", line 1, in <module>
    df[["A", "B", "A"]].sort("B")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas-0.13.0_212_g65b9815-py2.7-linux-i686.egg/pandas/core/frame.py", line 2664, in sort
    inplace=inplace)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas-0.13.0_212_g65b9815-py2.7-linux-i686.egg/pandas/core/frame.py", line 2756, in sort_index
    return self.take(indexer, axis=axis, convert=False, is_copy=False)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas-0.13.0_212_g65b9815-py2.7-linux-i686.egg/pandas/core/generic.py", line 1126, in take
    new_data = self._data.take(indices, axis=baxis)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas-0.13.0_212_g65b9815-py2.7-linux-i686.egg/pandas/core/internals.py", line 3326, in take
    ref_items=new_axes[0], axis=axis)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas-0.13.0_212_g65b9815-py2.7-linux-i686.egg/pandas/core/internals.py", line 2304, in apply
    do_integrity_check=do_integrity_check)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas-0.13.0_212_g65b9815-py2.7-linux-i686.egg/pandas/core/internals.py", line 1957, in __init__
    self._set_ref_locs(do_refs=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas-0.13.0_212_g65b9815-py2.7-linux-i686.egg/pandas/core/internals.py", line 2097, in _set_ref_locs
    'have _ref_locs set' % (block, labels))
AssertionError: Cannot create BlockManager._ref_locs because block [IntBlock: [A], 1 x 3, dtype: int64] with duplicate items [Index([u'A', u'B', u'A'], dtype='object')] does not have _ref_locs set
```

I'm not sure whether that was a typo on your part or whether you have duplicate column names or what, but if you avoid it, I think it should work.

Comment: Yes, the second 'net_pft_r' should be 'net_pft_gr'. It works now after I correct the typo. Thanks. But, 'sort()' should be able to accept duplicate columns.